# Catch dynamic column and write whole row to file

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I want to catch 4th column in that case which can be different string and on base of that string to put the whole row in file and to put also if some of that strings are repeat to the same file. Name of the file which I want to create is the name of the column 4th.

```
1 OI 021 141012 1321 0001242
1 OI 021 141013 1322 0001242
1 OI 021 141013 1323 0001242
1 OI 021 141012 1322 0001242
1 OI 021 141011 1321 0001242
```

Expectation which is hard to make is something like that:

file name `141011` contains:

```
1 OI 021 141011 1321 0001242
```

file name `141012` contains:

```
1 OI 021 141012 1321 0001242
1 OI 021 141012 1322 0001242
```

file name `141013` contains:

```
1 OI 021 141013 1322 0001242
1 OI 021 141013 1323 0001242
```

Comment: The explanation of the problem is a little unclear. You have mentioned something to do with repeated lines? Can you try and explain it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just redirect the `print` to the 4th field, which will be treated as file name:

```
awk '{print > $4}' file
```

In case these `14101*` files already exist and you want to append data, not truncate it, use `>>`:

```
awk '{print >> $4}' file
```

#### Test

```
$ awk '{print > $4}' file
$ tail 14101*
==> 141011 <==
1 OI 021 141011 1321 0001242

==> 141012 <==
1 OI 021 141012 1321 0001242
1 OI 021 141012 1322 0001242

==> 141013 <==
1 OI 021 141013 1322 0001242
1 OI 021 141013 1323 0001242
```